# How do I insert Excel date format (mm/dd/yyyy) into SQL Server format (yyyy-mm-dd)?

Tags: sql-server

There is already pre-inputed data in the Excel table in `dd/mm/yyyy` date format. How can I bulk insert the Excel values in a `.csv` file into the SQL Server table with `yyyy-mm-dd` date format?

Comment: FYI, your title says it's in `mm/dd/yyyy` and your question says `dd/mm/yyyy`. Also, `csv` files aren't Excel files, they're Comma Seperated Value Files. Excel file extensions start with `.xls`. What application you can open a file in doesn't make that file specifically a {Application Name} file. I can open `.jpg`, `.png` and `.gif` files in MS Paint, but that doesn't make them `Microsoft Paint files".

Comment: What **datatype** are your target columns in SQL Server?? If they are `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` (as they should be), they **don't have** a format - the format is only relevant when displaying the dates - the column themselves are **binary** without any formatting.

Comment: This question seems to be lacking a lot of details. Please edit the question to include the following: some sample lines from your CSV file; the schema of the table into which you're trying to insert data (i.e.: a `create table` statement); the Format File you've created to import the .csv file into the table; either the SQL `bulk insert` statement or the `bcp.exe` command line line you're using to actually perform the bulk insert.

Answer (score 0):

Well, CSV files don't have formatting, and 'bulk insert the Excel values in a .csv file' doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  If you want to push data from Excel to SQL Server, you have many options to do so.  If the data set is samll, you can use an Excel Macro to do the work.

```
Sub InsertInto()

'Declare some variables
Dim cnn As adodb.Connection
Dim cmd As adodb.Command
Dim strSQL As String

'Create a new Connection object
Set cnn = New adodb.Connection

'Set the connection string
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=Server_Name"


'Create a new Command object
Set cmd = New adodb.Command

'Open the Connection to the database
cnn.Open

'Associate the command with the connection
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

'Tell the Command we are giving it a bit of SQL to run, not a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Create the SQL
strSQL = "UPDATE TBL SET JOIN_DT = '2013-01-22' WHERE EMPID = 2"

'Pass the SQL to the Command object
cmd.CommandText = strSQL


'Execute the bit of SQL to update the database
cmd.Execute

'Close the connection again
cnn.Close

'Remove the objects
Set cmd = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you data really is in a CSV file, you can bulk insert the CSV data into SQL Server.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
BULK INSERT  OurTable 
FROM 'c:\OurTable.txt' 
WITH (CODEPAGE = 'RAW', DATAFILETYPE = 'char', FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', 
   ROWS_PER_BATCH = 10000, TABLOCK)
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Of course you can also go to SQL Server and import the CSV file from there.

https://www.sqlshack.com/importing-and-working-with-csv-files-in-sql-server/